# storyboard layout display issue for watchKit

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I have a storyboard for watch kit where I added a label, 2 groups and 3 buttons in those groups. See pic below. As you can see the whole screen looks filled and there is no space at the end after "Reset" button

[image]

When I run this in 48 simulator I get some spacing at the end. See pic. I understand that this is happening because I had set my label height to be fixed 67 but if I try to make it "relative to container" then it pushes all the buttons down out of the view. Is this how its suppose to work with space left at the end or can I do something about it? Any suggestions please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to select the groups you added and make their position vertically aligned to bottom.

[image]

In you screen shot, set the vertical positioning to Bottom not to top.